# Two Phase Commit/Shared Transaction

Tags: oracle

The scenario is this

We have two applications A and B, both which are running in separate database (Oracle 9i ) transactions

Application A - inserts some data into the database, then calls Application B
Application B - inserts some data into the database, related (via foreign keys) to A's data. Returns an "ID" to Application A
Application A - uses ID to insert further data, including the ID from B

Now, because these are separate transactions, but both rely on data from each others transactions, we need to commit between the calls to each application. This of course makes it very difficult to rollback if anything goes wrong.

How would you approach this problem, with minimal refactoring of the code. Surely this kind of this is a common problem in the SOA world?

------ Update --------

I have not been able to find anything in Oracle 9i, however Oracle 11g provides [DBMS_XA](http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/dbms_xa.html), which does exactly what I was after.

Comment: I don't think the tags are relevant. java, perl, jboss aren't even mentioned in the question, and the problem isn't specific to oracle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Redesign the application so that you don't have two different processes (both with database connections) writing to the database and roll it into a single app.
2. Create application C that handles all the database transactions for A and B.
3. Roll your own two phase commit. Application C acts as the coordinator. C signals A and B to ask if they're ready to commit. A and B do their processing, and respond to C with either a "ready" or a "fail" reply (note that there should be a timeout on C to avoid an infinite wait if one process hangs or dies). If both reply ready then C tells them to commit. Otherwise it sends a rollback signal.

Note that you may run into issues with option 3 if app A is relying on foreign keys from app B (which you didn't state, so this may not be an issue). Oracle's read consistency would probably prevent this from being allowed, since app A's transaction will begin before app B. Just a warning.

Comment: I feared this would be the case, was hoping someone knew something I didn't. Will wait to see if anyone else has something magical to offer, if not will accept answer.

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions:

- Use [Compensating transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensating_transaction). Basically, you make it possible to undo the transaction you did earlier. The hard part is figuring out which transactions to rollback.
- Commit the data of applications A and B to the database using a flag indicating that it is only temporary. Then, after everything checks out fine, modify the flag to indicate that the data is final. During the night, run a batch job to flush out data that has not been finalized.

Comment: Watch out: The second option can leave "the world" in an inconsistent state: `A` might have a finalized transaction while `B` doesn't have the corresponding transaction. This is better done with two-phase commit.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably insert the data from Application A into a 'temporary' area so that Application B can do the inserts of both A and B without changing much in either appplications.  It's not particularly elegant but it might do the trick.

In another scenario you could add a 'confirmation' flag field to your data which is updated after the entire process has run successfully.  It if fails at one point, it might be easier to track down the records you need to rollback (in effect, delete).

Answer (score 1):

I like both solutions presented, so I avoided posting this for a while. But you could also make an update to the main table, having saved the state of the affected rows in some cache before hand.

This could be combined with the two-tier (The traffic cop system Zathrus proposed)--because it really wouldn't be needed for neonski's solution of using a "sketchpad" table or tables. The drawback of this is that you would have to have your procs/logic consult the main table from the workarea or the workarea from the main table--or perhaps store your flag in the main table and set it back when you commit the data to the main table.

A lady on our team is designing something like that for our realtime system, using permanent work tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
App_A =={0}=>               database # App_A stores information for App_B
App_A ------> App_B                  # App_A starts App_B
              App_B <={0}== database # App_B retrieves the information
              App_B =={1}=> database # App_B stores more informaion
App_A <={2}== App_B                  # App_B returns 'ID' to App_A
App_A ={2,3}>               database # App_A stores 'ID' and additional data
```

Is it just me or does it seem like Application B is essentially just a subroutine of A. I mean Application B doesn't do anything until A asks it, and Application A doesn't do anything until B returns an ID. Which means it makes little sense to have them in different applications, or even separate threads.

Comment: Application A inserts data into the database required by B, it then inserts more data returned from B.

Comment: I know how it works in actuality, I was just trying to explain it in a more abstracted way.